# button's text does not return to its original position after increase and decrease its size on HoneyComb

Tags: android

The next code shows three buttons. You can increase and decrease the text size of one of those buttons , called 'main' button. The main button also has an image (compound drawable)

You'll note that the text position will change (Eg: increase the text to a big size, and then decrease it to its original size ). Also, you can see the text size changes int  logcat.
This behavior is reproduced in android 3.1 
This behavior is not reproduced in android 2.2

Why is this happening?

the code:

```
public class Acc extends Activity {
/**
 * main button
 */
Button b;
/*
 * the text size
 */
float textSize;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b = new Button(this);  //create main button
    b.setText("I'm main button"); //set its text
    b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.icon, 0, 0); //add a drawable 
    textSize=14;//assign initial textsize
    b.setTextSize(textSize); //set it to the button's text size
    b.setHeight(200);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); //get the activity layout
    layout.addView(b); //add the main button to the layout

    addZoomInOutButtons(layout); //add two buttons to increase and decrease the main button's height and text size 
    Log.v("my log","FIRST TIME: text size:"+textSize);
}
/**
 * Create two buttons, to increase and decrease with and text size of main button
 * @param layout
 */
private void addZoomInOutButtons(LinearLayout layout){
    Button bzi = new Button(this);
    bzi.setText("zoom in");

    Button bzo = new Button(this);
    bzo.setText("zoom out");

    layout.addView(bzi);
    layout.addView(bzo);

    bzi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textSize+=10;
            b.setTextSize(textSize);
            Log.v("my log","text size:"+textSize);
        }

    });
    bzo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textSize-=10;
            b.setTextSize(textSize);
            Log.v("my log","text size:"+textSize);
        }

    });
}
```

}

also the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Acc"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```